# Change ionic button state

Tags: angularjs, button, ionic-framework

At first,sorry for my poor English.
I have some questions of the ionic buttons.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDN7Y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Yph.png)

just like the image,when i click one of them,the other button change its background-color buy itself .

can you help me?

Comment: I would waiting for answers.

Comment: you have to share code , then only we can help you.

Comment: i don't know how to write the code . i just know what i want to display.you can click the link ,then you can see the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/3Lsb8oab/8/

The code uses [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive to change class of buttons based on a $scope property value (btn):

```
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <button class="button" ng-class="{'button-assertive': btn == 1}" ng-click="btn = 2">
          First
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <button class="button" ng-class="{'button-assertive': btn == 2}" ng-click="btn = 1">
          Second
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```